# Regular expression to match url and ignore querystring

Tags: regex, wordpress, plugins, redirect

I have migrated my old asp.net  website to wordpress and i now am trying  to do 301 redirect gracefully .
I am trying to do it by using regular  expression with [this](https://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/redirection/) plugin.

My source url is

```
http://example.com/outlets/19-awok?page=2
```

Target url is `http://example.com/shop/awok/`

I want to get the shop name and ignore everything else coming after it

My try :

```
/outlets/(\d+)-(.*)? => /shop/$2
```

Another example source  url   http://example.com/outlets/105-big-bazar?page=453

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, you could exclude the question mark with a negated character class:

```
/outlets/(\d+)-([^?]+) => /shop/$2
```

Your initial approach made the complete second group optional.

---

If you don't need the leading digits, you could as well do

```
/outlets/[-\d]+([^?]+) => /shop/$1
```

Mind the `$1` instead of `$2` in the latter.

Comment: thank you its working .one more question ..is there any way to ignore query string also ? ie, i need just 'shop/awok/'